# Unable to do any other action than "alert" when triggering the click event on Highcharts (React Native)

Tags: react-native, highcharts, onclick

- Im using Highcharts in React Native
- For a bar chart I have the following click event defined:

  ```
  plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: () => {
                          alert("Clicked!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
          }
  ```
- I would like to setState on the click event to be able to display the elements of the clicked bar, but I cant even console.log() on it.
- I checked examples and all I saw was "alerts" inside the callback function.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

[image: bar chart]

Comment: Have you tried `click: () => { console.log("Clicked!"); }` or `click: () => { this.setState({yourKey: yourValue}); }` and neither of them worked?

Comment: @Andrew that's right, I tried both and just nothing happens. The only thing that works is the alert.

Comment: Hi @Diego Leonvendagar, the behavior you describe seems very strange. Do you use any wrapper for Highcharts?

Comment: @ppotaczek I'm doing exactly this: https://github.com/TradingPal/react-native-highcharts

Comment: @Diego Leonvendagar, I would advise you to contact the author directly by creating an issue: https://github.com/TradingPal/react-native-highcharts/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working now! The problem was the following (as I understand it):

- Highcharts for React Native renders the chart within a WebView. For this reason only alerts can be made.
- If you try to console.log directly (or call a method or anything else) it won't work because it's not getting to React Native, it's in the webview.
- So the question was: how to pass data from the webview to React Native? And the answer iiiiis... window.postMessage()

Like this:

1. In the config object (passed to the chart):

   ```
   plotOptions: {
         series: {
             point: {
                 events: {
                     click: function() {
                       window.postMessage( //data you want to send to react native )
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
       }
   ```
2. Pass the onMessage method as prop to the ChartView such as you would pass it to a WebView (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview#onmessage)

   ```
   <ChartView style={{ height: 300 }} config={conf} onMessage={m => onMessage(m)} options={options}></ChartView>
   ```
3. Just now you can console.log, setState, or do anything in your react native onMessage function

   ```
   onMessage = (m) => { 
      console.log(m.nativeEvent.data)
   }
   ```

And that's it, now I can click a bar and change the state of my component ;)

Comment: I am having a hard time using the `window.postMessage()` part. What exactly do you send there, exactly a JSON?

Comment: @fedorqui you can send anything. I just send a string representing the key of the clicked bar. It doesn't have to be necessarily a JSON at all. You can do something like window.postMessage('hello').

Comment: Oh, cool! I had something similar in [How can I add links in a Highcharts tooltip that will open on mobile's browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55358659/1983854) and ended up using a similar approach. It does work on iOS, but not in Android though. Did you experience the same problem?

Comment: Yeah I got that problem recently when I updated the Expo version to 32. I fixed it by adding the following props to the ChartView component:
1. originWhitelist={['*']}
2. useWebKit={true}

These comment really helped me: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/3168#issuecomment-473727850

And there's more info here: 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2018/08/27/wkwebview
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview#originwhitelist

Let me know if it worked!

Comment: <ChartView 
            style={{ height: 200 }} 
            config={conf} 
            options={options} 
            onMessage={m => onMessage(m)}
            originWhitelist={['*']}  
            useWebKit={true}
>
</ChartView>

Comment: No, it did not work :( As I posted in [How can I make React Native in Android aware of a click event in a tooltip in a Highcharts chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55589594/1983854) it looks as if Android needs some timeout before sending the message, but my attempts were not successful.

Comment: I managed to solve it using `window.__REACT_WEB_VIEW_BRIDGE.postMessage` instead of `window.postMessage` on Android. Many thanks for your help in this issue, I wish I could upvote more than once :)

Answer (score 1):

Only alert supports since Highcharts is rendering inside Webview.
 so for this

```
let data = "ClickedWebView" ;
```

- Any message it could be *
  Note : window.postMessage will not work .
  WebView version > 5 gives us this modified function,

write the following code in  config as

```
plotOptions: {
      series: {
          point: {
              events: {
                  click: function() {
                   window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(data);
                  }
              }
          }
      }
    }
```

in ChartView Code Code would be

```
<ChartView style={{ height: 400 }} config={confi} onMessage={m => this.onMessage(m)} options={options}></ChartView>
```

can write custom message function as

```
onMessage = (message) => { 
   console.log(message.nativeEvent.data)
}
```

Comment: You saved my life ReactNativeWebView whas the key. thaks a lot 